# Windows hard drive won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, 14.04, window

I am a Windows 7 64-bit user and decided to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a separate hard drive. Everything went perfectly until I wanted to boot Windows again. I was not able to do it even though I entered the BIOS and it still recognizes the Windows hard drive (and I can see the Windows files from Ubuntu).

I tried unplugging the Ubuntu hard drive, and it says the machine needs a device to boot from.

Is there anything I can do to fix this and have both operating systems on separate hard drives? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do can run both OS on separate drives. To do so, the boot manager (grub2?) must be installed on the hard drive with the higher boot order (1?).

To get back windows 7, running Windows repair should do the trick. Use a live usb, it shouldn't be tough.

If you're lucky enough, you will get Grub working perfectly (Yes, windows can "repair" grub, I know what I'm talking about, I saw it with my eyes). If not, you'll at least get Windows 7 working. All you need to do now is using boot-repair with the right settings (flush grub, install on the right disk, ...).

Good luck.

You can get Windows 7 repair either from an installation disk, a working Windows 7 or from some dark places over the web.
You can get boot repair on a live usb using a secure-remix iso or installing it this way :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's grub which doesn't let you access Windows 7, the program "boot repair" should work for it. If it's Windows 7 which got corrupted after Ubuntu installation, you'd better follow LittleNooby suggestion